# Inserting an element into multi dimension vector errors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing a program where I'm creating a lab with multidimensional vectors. So far I have a constructor that asks the user to input number and sizes of a lab. In the program I'm creating a function called addLab that add a new lab at the specified position with number of computers inputted by user.

While testing the program I make the user input the number of sizes of the lab to be 3 then I tried adding lab 5 to the vector but I get the following output which doesn't compile correctly:

```
labs: Computer Stations:
1:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
2:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
3:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
Where do you want the lab inserted at?
```

Here is my header file

```
#ifndef __grade_weight_calculator__ComputerLabs__
#define __grade_weight_calculator__ComputerLabs__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class ComputerLabs{
public:
    ComputerLabs();
    void show_labs();
    void add_lab();
private:
    vector<vector<string>> labs;
    int numoflab;
    int numofcomp;
    int lab_numba;
    int comp_numba;
};

#endif
```

Here is my implementation cpp file

```
#include "ComputerLabs.h"

ComputerLabs::ComputerLabs()
{
    cout<<"Input the number of labs"<<endl;
    cin>>numoflab;
    cout<<"Input the size of the labs"<<endl;
    cin>>numofcomp;

    for (int i=0;i<numoflab; i++){
           vector<string> row;
        for (int j=0;j<numofcomp; j++)
            row.push_back("empty");
        labs.push_back(row);
    }
}

void ComputerLabs::show_labs()
{
    cout<<"labs: "<<"Computer Stations:"<<endl;

    int a=0;
    int j;

    for (int i=0;i<numoflab; i++){
        cout<<a+1<<":    ";

        j=0;
        while(j<numofcomp){
            cout<<"  ";
            cout<<j+1<<":"<<labs[i][j];
            ++j;
        }
        a++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void ComputerLabs::add_lab()
{
    cout<<"Where do you want the lab inserted at?"<<endl;
    numoflab=5;//this makes it add lab 5


    vector<string> row;
    for(int i=0;i<numofcomp;i++)
    {
        row.push_back("empty");
    }
    labs.insert(labs.begin()+4,row);
 }
```

And here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include "ComputerLabs.h"

int main()
{
    ComputerLabs mycomp;

    mycomp.show_labs();
    mycomp.add_lab();
    mycomp.show_labs();
 }
```

I think another error that might be causing this relates to show_labs() function in terms of the algorithm I tried using but im not entirely too sure. Can anyone help me figure out my issues and the solution for fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is in the `add_lab()` function.

```
void ComputerLabs::add_lab()
{
    cout<<"Where do you want the lab inserted at?"<<endl;

    // PROBLEM LINE
    // Not sure why you needed to do that.
    // When the initial value of numoflab is 3, 
    // numoflabs can be changed to 4 but not 5. If you set it
    // to 5 here, you run into problem in show_lab() since
    // there aren't 5 rows in your 2D vector.
    numoflab=5;//this makes it add lab 5


    vector<string> row;
    for(int i=0;i<numofcomp;i++)
    {
        row.push_back("empty");
    }
    labs.insert(labs.begin()+4,row);
 }
```

Change that function to:

```
void ComputerLabs::add_lab()
{
    cout<<"Where do you want the lab inserted at?"<<endl;
    int pos;
    cin >> pos;

    // Make sure that the input position is valid.
    if ( pos > numoflab )
    {
       cout << "Invalid position." << endl;
       return;
    }

    // Increment numoflab by 1
    ++numoflab;

    std::vector<std::string> tempRow;
    for(int i=0;i<numofcomp;i++)
    {
       tempRow.push_back("empty");
    }
    labs.insert(labs.begin()+pos, tempRow);
}
```

**General Improvements**

You don't need to store `numoflab` in your class as a member variable. It can be derived from `labs`.

I see that you have already updated your code so that `row` is not a member variable of the class any more.

As a matter of good design, it's better to provide the class with its data rather than expecting the class to get the data from `stdin` or `cin`.

Here's an updated version of your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class ComputerLabs {
   public:
      ComputerLabs(int numoflab, int numofcomp);
      void show_labs();
      void add_lab(int pos);
   private:
      vector<vector<string>> labs;
      int numofcomp;
      int lab_numba;
      int comp_numba;
};

ComputerLabs::ComputerLabs(int numoflab, int numofcomp) : numofcomp(numofcomp)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numoflab; i++){
      std::vector<std::string> row;
      for (int j = 0; j < numofcomp; j++)
      {
         row.push_back("empty");
      }
      labs.push_back(row);
   }
}

void ComputerLabs::show_labs()
{
   cout << "labs: " << "Computer Stations:" << endl;

   int numoflab = labs.size();
   for (int i = 0; i<numoflab; i++){
      cout << i+1 << ":    ";

      for (int j = 0; j < numofcomp; j++)
      {
         cout<<"  ";
         cout << j+1 << ":" << labs[i][j];
      }
      cout<<endl;
   }
}

void ComputerLabs::add_lab(int pos)
{
   int numoflab = labs.size();
   if ( pos < 0 || pos > numoflab )
   {
      cout << "Invalid position." << endl;
      return;
   }

   std::vector<std::string> row;
   for(int i=0;i<numofcomp;i++)
   {
      row.push_back("empty");
   }
   labs.insert(labs.begin()+pos,row);
}

int main()
{
   int numoflab;
   int numofcomp;

   cout << "Input the number of labs" << endl;
   cin >> numoflab;
   cout << "Input the size of the labs" << endl;
   cin >> numofcomp;

   if (!cin )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   ComputerLabs mycomp(numoflab, numofcomp);

   mycomp.show_labs();

   cout << "Where do you want the lab inserted at?" << endl;
   int pos;
   cin >> pos;
   if (!cin )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   mycomp.add_lab(pos);
   mycomp.show_labs();
}
```

**Update**

If you would like sizes of the newly added labs to be different from the sizes of existing labs, you can do the following:

1. Remove `numofcomp` as a member variable.
2. Add another argument to `add_lab`, `numofcomp`.
3. Before calling `add_lab`, ask the user for the number of components of the lab.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class ComputerLabs {
   public:
      ComputerLabs(int numoflab, int numofcomp);
      void show_labs();
      void add_lab(int pos, int numofcomp);
   private:
      vector<vector<string>> labs;
};

ComputerLabs::ComputerLabs(int numoflab, int numofcomp)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numoflab; i++){
      std::vector<std::string> row;
      for (int j = 0; j < numofcomp; j++)
      {
         row.push_back("empty");
      }
      labs.push_back(row);
   }
}

void ComputerLabs::show_labs()
{
   cout << "labs: " << "Computer Stations:" << endl;

   int numoflab = labs.size();
   for (int i = 0; i<numoflab; i++){
      cout << i+1 << ":    ";

      int numofcomp = labs[i].size();
      for (int j = 0; j < numofcomp; j++)
      {
         cout<<"  ";
         cout << j+1 << ":" << labs[i][j];
      }
      cout<<endl;
   }
}

void ComputerLabs::add_lab(int pos,
                           int numofcomp)
{
   int numoflab = labs.size();
   if ( pos < 0 || pos > numoflab )
   {
      cout << "Invalid position." << endl;
      return;
   }

   std::vector<std::string> row;
   for(int i=0;i<numofcomp;i++)
   {
      row.push_back("empty");
   }
   labs.insert(labs.begin()+pos,row);
}

int main()
{
   int numoflab;
   int numofcomp;

   cout << "Input the number of labs" << endl;
   cin >> numoflab;
   cout << "Input the size of the labs" << endl;
   cin >> numofcomp;

   if (!cin )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   ComputerLabs mycomp(numoflab, numofcomp);

   mycomp.show_labs();

   cout << "Where do you want the lab inserted at?" << endl;
   int pos;
   cin >> pos;
   cout << "Input the size of the lab" << endl;
   cin >> numofcomp;

   if (!cin )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   mycomp.add_lab(pos, numofcomp);
   mycomp.show_labs();
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu The directions for my addlab is-" add a new lab at the specified position with number of computers inputted by user" so if i had three labs to begin (ex. lab 1, lab 2, lab 3) then I should have lab 1 lab 2 lab 3 lab 5 if i wanted to add a lab 5. I might be misunderstanding the directions and what i said earlier can never happen but what im trying to say isnt there a way for me to keep changing the rows everytime i wanted to insert a new lab?

Comment: @guploo, there is definitely some misunderstanding here. Either it's you or it's me. If you have 3 labs and you add another lab, there will be 4 labs at the end. Where can "lab 5" come from?

Comment: @R Sahu Well in that case If I had three labs lab 1, lab 2 and lab 3 then using the addLab function whats positions can I insert the new lab in? is it just position 4 or can the new lab also be added at position 1 2 and 3? Sorry if what I'm saying might be dim!

Comment: @guploo, When you have three labs, you can insert another lab at positions 0, 1, 2, and 3. In my suggested code, I have a line that checks for the correctness of the position.

Comment: @R Sahu oh ok I believe I understand now and I can handle the rest of the assignment on my own. Thank you for taking time in actually showing me my errors and improving my code along with teaching me some useful tips!

Comment: @R Sahu I just remembered an important question!! When adding a new lab how do I also let the user decide the size of the lab? Sorry I know I said last question but I'm having trouble figuring out the trick

Comment: Are you suggesting that `numofcomp` can be different than the value of the member variable?

Comment: @R Sahu When you are adding a lab then yes (the size of the lab is given by the user)

Comment: @guploo, in that case, what's the purpose of the member variable `numofcomp`?

Comment: @R Sahu numofcomp stores the size of the lab. It changes whenever the user wants to create a lab that has a different size each time

Comment: @guploo, `labs.size()` gives you the number of labs. Each item of `labs` is also a vector, whose size you get by using the `size()` member function. If the size of each item of `labs` can be different, how is `numofcomp` useful?

Comment: @R Sahu I only wanted to use numofcomp in the beginning of the program when the user initalizes the number of labs and size of each lab. After that I was going to use labs.size() for changing the number of labs and labs.capacity() for the size of each lab. My problem that i dont know how to make the capacity different for some of the labs

Comment: @guploo, see my update. Hope that addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```
numoflab = 5; // number of labs increased by 2 (from 3)

for(int i = 0; i < numofcomp; i++)
{
    row.push_back("empty");
}

labs.insert(labs.begin() + 3, row); // you added only one lab (or row), (the program expects one more to 5)
```

You've got to insert one more row, do `labs.insert(labs.begin() + 4, row)` again for example. (`labs.begin() + 3` or `labs.begin() + 4` is also perfectly valid.)

You also have a very silly bug in your code, which is using `vector<string> row` as a member. Now, each time you `push_back`, `row` grows in size, but it's never cleared (except at the end of the program). If you printed the whole rows instead of just 3, you'd get this:

```
labs: Computer Stations:
1:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
2:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty  4:empty  5:empty  6:empty
3:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty  4:empty  5:empty  6:empty  7:empty  8:empty  9:empty
```

Very bad. You don't need `row` to be a member, you can make it local (create and destroy it in every function in which you insert the rows). In the `ComputerLabs` constructor, it can even be inside the scope of the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numoflab; i++) {
    vector<string> row; // constructed every iteration

    for (int j = 0;j < numofcomp; j++)
        row.push_back("empty");

    labs.push_back(row); // row is copied
    // row is destroyed
}
```

Comment: @ LogicStuff I changed my constructor definition to what you wrote, removed vector<string> row as a member,  and in my add_lab() function I changed  labs.insert(labs.begin() + 3, row); into labs.insert(labs.begin() + 4, row); and declared vector<string> row above for(int i = 0; i < numofcomp; i++)
{
    row.push_back("empty");
} but im still getting errors in my code

Comment: My output is 

labs: Computer Stations:
1:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
2:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
3:      1:empty  2:empty  3:empty
Where do you want the lab inserted at?//at this point idk what is happening  the program is doing nothing but still running

Comment: @guploo Then show me what you've done with `add_lab` function. Add it to the question.

Comment: I updated the question along with my functions with the changes that you showed me

Comment: @guploo Oh, you want to add lab 5 but not 4? For that, you'll need to have vector of labs, lab is a class that has its number and vector of corporations. But if you had `labs.insert(labs.begin()+3,row);` before `labs.insert(labs.begin()+4,row);` you'd have 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes I want lab 5 but not lab 4. I thought I have a vector of labs. Well anyways how would I create a vector of labs if what I have isnt a vector of labs?

Comment: `class Lab { public: int number; vector<string> companies; };` - this is your lab. First, make this one trustworthy (add constructor and other stuff you want) and then deal with `ComputerLabs` - there will be simply `vector<Lab> labs;`. And this is the last thing I'll write - instead of member `int`s you should then use `labs.size()` to get the numer of labs, and `labs[n].size()` to get the individual size of a lab (they can differ).